# Method Not Found: "Boolean AddToCartModel.get_BtnHideOnStatus" added new property in addToCart Model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nopcommerce

I am working in `nop commerce 3.8` and in `Nop.web`, I have added new property name "`BtnHideOnStatus`" in AddToCart. I start my application then no bug comes but  when i restart again then the error comes with `"Method Not Found."`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks @halfer i will keep it in my mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue i found the duplicate old dlls and delete that Nop.web dll in another plugin folders.

Here is the reference link
https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/21925/a-route-named-homepage-is-already-in-the-route-collection-route-names-must-be-unique.aspx